# Get average time between two columns and several rows MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns one containing a start TIMESTAMP and one containing a END TIMESTAMP. I want to calculate the average time between start and end over all records. Currently I tried the following:

```
$result = $conn->query( $sql );

$averages = array();

$result = $conn->query( $sql ); # Place the result into an array
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {


            $sum = 0;

        if($EndColumn == ' '){
            $time = $row[$StartColumn];

        }else{
        $time = strtotime($row[$EndColumn]) - strtotime($row[$StartColumn]);    

            $averages[] = $time; 
         }

        }
    $total = array_sum($averages);

    $count = count($averages);

        $avg = $total/$count;
    return round(($total/$count));
```

This is not working correctly at all, I think this can be accomplished in the sql string itself but am too stupid to figure it out. Either way please help!

Comment: For the purposes of the question, get rid of all of the above and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `This is not working correctly at all` what happen exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
   SELECT CAST(AVG(start_date + (IFNULL(end_date,start_date)-start_date)/2) AS DATETIME) AS average_date FROM TableName
```

If dates are stored as timestamp then above query will give average time between start and end over all records.

Answer (score 0):

**Average between times**

With columns using the timestamp field

```
Select AVG(timediff(T1, T2)) as time_average from TableName
```

**Average between dates**

With columns using the datetime field

```
Select AVG(datediff(D1, D2)) as date_average from TableName
```

Comment: Ah I missed that. Not sure if I should delete this post. It's not a direct answer but might be helpful to someone searching for a solution to the "Get average time between two columns and several rows MYSQL" problem in the future.

Comment: Maybe not delete but edit with both solution one for timestamp, the other for date could be wise, also explain that on MYSQL D1 and D2 have to be in Date or DateTime to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. You will get avg time in second. More details https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

```
Select AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttimestamp, endtimestamp)) from TableName
```