# Average time between two time frames MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, average

Ive been tasked to find the average time taken between two actions for users.
It's an app for  people to find other basketball players to play with.

Ive been tasked to find the average time between joining a game and game due date

I have table with the **game_users** that contains the following columns
created at refers to join time

```
game_id | User_id | created_at  
345     | 234     | 2019-01-16 14:09:51
```

And there is another table with the game details **games** that contains the following columns

```
id  | game_status | game_due_date
345 | Completed   | 2020-10-19 04:30:00
```

So, how can I find the average time between the two time frames?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700657/get-average-time-between-two-columns-and-several-rows-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two tables and then use `DATEDIFF` to find the number of days in between the two time frames:

```sql
SELECT
    gu.game_id,
    gu.User_id,
    DATEDIFF(COALESCE(g.game_due_date, gu.created_at), gu.created_at) AS days_between
FROM games_users gu
LEFT JOIN games g
    ON gu.game_id = g.id;
```